# In SQL Server 2014, how do I edit values in a specific column, all rows?

Tags: sql-server, search, replace, edit

I have a table with a column that provides a link to a folder location of an item, I need to remove erroneous UNC paths and update them to a mapped drive path:

Correct path:

```
Z:\Delta Pipeline\JOB FOLDER\Archived Jobs\Millie Severson\2458 Watson 867\Plans\BidSet\DPR020211BidSet\
```

Incorrect path:

```
\\server1\data\Delta Pipeline\JOB FOLDER\Millie Severson\GoodSamaritan\Plans\DPR042310ApprovedDrwgs\
```

Comment: Why is the correct path so very different from the incorrect path?  Can you please use the same example for the before and after...?

Comment: the incorrect path is a UNC path, we are migrating servers and the new server does not have the same name, the UNC paths are there by user error in the application, However we really just want to edit 'back' the path to replace \\server1\data with z:\

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are multiple records in this table that you want to update, you can do the following to replace the `\\server1\data\` portion with `Z:\`:

```
Update  YourTable
Set     YourColumn = Replace(YourColumn, '\\server1\data\', 'Z:\')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE myTab SET yourColumn = 'Z:\Delta Pipeline\JOB FOLDER\Archived Jobs\Millie Severson\2458 Watson 867\Plans\BidSet\DPR020211BidSet\' 
WHERE myTab.yourColumn = '\server1\data\Delta Pipeline\JOB FOLDER\Millie Severson\GoodSamaritan\Plans\DPR042310ApprovedDrwgs\'
```